# How do I parse text into lists in Java?

Tags: java, parsing

I have the following file saved as a `.txt`:

```
I Did It Your Way, 11.95
The History of Scotland, 14.50
Learn Calculus in One Day, 29.95
Feel the Stress, 18.50
Great Poems, 12.95
Europe on a Shoestring, 10.95
The Life of Mozart, 14.50
```

I need to display the title of the books and the prices on different `JList`s in Java.  How do I do that?

Also if I have an array with two values (once I separate the title from the price) how do I copy the title and price into their respective arrays?

Comment: Is it possible for a title to have a comma in it?

Answer (score 4):

Seems simple enough that you don't need anything fancy.

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Double> prices = new ArrayList<Double>();

while ((String line = r.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] tokens = line.split(",");
  titles.add(tokens[0].trim());
  prices.add(Double.parseDouble(tokens[1].trim()));
}

r.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are separated by comma, you can use http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ . Here is the sample code,

```
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
    List myEntries = reader.readAll();

    int noOfEntries=myEntries.size();

    String[] titles=new String[noOfEntries]; 
    String[] price=new String[noOfEntries]; 

    String[] entry=null;
    int i=0;
    for(Object entryObject:myEntries){
        entry=(String[]) entryObject;
        titles[i]=entry[0];
        price[i]=entry[1];
        i++;
            }
```